# Ordenar Array de JSON-Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array

Tengo un array de JSON en un arreglo llamado `var ArregloDatos`:

**ArregloDatos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resulta que quiero ordenar este arreglo del tal forma que el mismo se orden de menor a mayor dependiendo su nombre, es decir en el ejemplo anterior tendría que ser "`Ana-Hernan-Victor`", uso la siguiente función:

```
//FUNCION QUE ORDENA POR NOMBRE LOS ARREGLOS
    function OrdenarPorNombre(x, y) {
        return ((x.nombre == y.nombre) ? 0 : ((x.nombre > y.nombre) ? 1 : -1));
    }
```

Pero a la hora de querer imprimir el resultado del arreglo:

```
console.log(ArregloDatos.sort(OrdenarPorNombre));
```

El problema que veo es que queda de la forma `[{nombre:xxx, apellido:xxxx}],[{nombre:xxx, apellido:xxxx}]`y no de la forma `[{nombre:xxx, apellido:xxxx},{nombre:xxx, apellido:xxxx}]` pero no se como puedo unirlos que en lugar que quede en un arreglo de arreglos quede un solo bloque JSON

Comment: de menor a mayor o alfabeticamente? y no es un array de objetos, es un array de arrays

Comment: los datos te llegan del servidor? o tu armas esa estructura?

Comment: @PieroPajares armo la estructura, es que no son datos todos a la vez, si no es que me ingresan por ejemplo esos 4 datos(nombre,apellido,edad,residencia), convierto eso a JSON y despues lo agrego al array, siento que los ejemplos que tomo es como un bloque completo de JSON y no JSON separados como tengo yo (asi lo veo yo, no se si por ahi sea el problema)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto es un array de objetos en el cual cada "{}" es un objeto y "[]" es el array que contiene todos los objetos.

```
array_objetos = [
      {"nombre": "Piero", "apellido": "Pajares"},
      {"nombre": "Alejandro", "apellido": "Orihuela"},
      {"nombre": "Daniel", "apellido": "Rojales"},
    ]
```

Ahora a ese array de objetos lo ordenas como lo estuviste haciendo:

```
array_objetos.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.nombre;
    var textB = b.nombre;
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
console.log(array_objetos)
```

Lu unico que tienes que hacer si los datos te llegan del servidor es guardarlos todos en un solo array "[]" por ejemplo te llega un array de objetos de personas:

```
array_personas = [
          {"nombre": "Piero", "apellido": "Pajares"},
          {"nombre": "Alejandro", "apellido": "Orihuela"},
          {"nombre": "Daniel", "apellido": "Rojales"},
        ]
```

recorres el array e insertas en el array que quieres que esten todos los objetos:

```
array_personas.forEach(function(element) {
  array_objetos.push(element)
});
```

Comment: El problema es que me llegan de la forma: `[{nombre:xx,apellido:xxx}]`, entonces lo guardo en un array, al final si tengo 2 en el array seria: `[{}],[{}]`, y no queda de la forma: `[{},{}]`, entonces siento que por ahi es el problema

Comment: Por cierto, no llegan juntos, es solo un form con 4 inputs donde entran esos datos y los mismo se convierten en JSON, uno a la vez

Comment: por eso @Baker1562 ahi te explico para que esos array separados "[{}],[{}]" los unas en un solo array recorriendo cada uno e insertandolo en uno solo

Comment: @PieroPajares me sirvió la respuesta Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar por otro atributo una solución alternativa es crear un arreglo con las posiciones deseadas:

```
ordenamiento = {"nivel básico": 1, "nivel intermedio": 2, "nivel avanzado": 3};
```

Y ahora lo que debemos hacer es usar el método sort() con una breve modificación:

```
this.misCursos.sort((
      (a, b) => this.ordenamiento[a.nivel] - this.ordenamiento[b.nivel])
    ));
```

Respuesta original tomada de [este blog](https://davidyero.medium.com/ordenar-arreglo-de-objetos-por-propiedad-o-atributo-javascript-56f74fc48906)