# Ordenar mi arreglo JSON por id react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Nesecito ordenar mi arreglo JSON por Id, al cargar la poagina sale desordenado nose como podria hacerlo este es una parte de mi codigo en react

el orden de los tag seria:

1. Ox. Dis
2. Temp
3. Ox. sat
4. Presion

El codigo es solo de una de las sala por ejemplo myDatachart1 corresponde a la sala 1

```
{
 myDataChart1
.filter((data) =>   favoritos.includes(data._id))
.map((data, i)=>
<Col sm="6"  key={data._id}  className={cx(data.active ? '' : 'opacity-3')}> 
<div className="widget-chart widget-chart-hover  p-0 p-0 ">
<Button 
 onClick={ e => this.slider1.slickGoTo(i)}
 key={data._id} className="btn-icon-vertical btn-square btn-transition p-3" outline color={miscolores[i]}>  
<div className="size-boton mt-0  " style={{color:miscolores[i]}} >                                                    
{data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value}
<span className="opacity-6  pl-0 size_unidad">  {data.unity} </span>
</div>
<div className="widget-subheading">
 {data.shortName}
</div>
</Button>  
</div>
</Col>
)   }
```

desde aqui se carga la api

```
  loadDataChar = () => {
    console.log("refresh");
    let now = new Date(); 
    const f1 = moment(now).subtract(12, "hours").format('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00') + ".000Z";
    const f2 = moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:59') + ".000Z";    

    const API1 = `${API_ROOT}/tag/location/${S1}/${f1}/${f2}`;       
    //console.log(API1);
    //const token = localStorage.getItem("token");        
    const token = "tokenfalso";
    axios
    .get(API1, {
      headers: {  
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
        const myDataChart1 = response.data.data; 


        this.setState({ myDataChart1,isLoading: false }); 

        console.log(myDataChart1);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Desde donde envías el json? Porque no lo envías ordenado?

Comment: que tal si  usas el [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)

Comment: Ya lo he hecho y no me realiza ningun cambio, o lo debo estar aplicando mal si me pueden ayudar gracias

Comment: Quizá esto te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266836/ordenar-array-de-json-javascript

Comment: Respecto a que los quieres ordenar? como es la estructura de tus datos? con esto podria ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 1):

Si _id es un ***string*** puedes organizarlo así:

**Ascendente**

```
 myDataChart1
.filter((data) =>   favoritos.includes(data._id))
.sort((a,b) => a._id.localeCompare(b._id))
```

**Descendente**

```
 myDataChart1
.filter((data) =>   favoritos.includes(data._id))
.sort((a,b) => b._id.localeCompare(a._id))
```

---

Si _id es un ***número*** puedes organizarlo así:

**Ascendente**

```
 myDataChart1
.filter((data) =>   favoritos.includes(data._id))
.sort((a,b) => a._id - b._id)
```

**Descendente**

```
 myDataChart1
.filter((data) =>   favoritos.includes(data._id))
.sort((a,b) => b._id - a._id)
```